# How does this sorting function work?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm learning javascript from FreeCodeCamp Curriculum, and I came across this sorting function.

```
var array = [1, 12, 21, 2];

// Only change code below this line.

array.sort(function(a,b){
  return b - a;
});
```

That sorting function is used to sort the elements of the array in decreasing order, I just don't get how. 
Could someone please explain me?

Comment: Did you try to step through it in the debugger line by line?

Comment: you have full and very documented explain here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Hm ok sorry, I should have tried :c

Comment: The `sort` method sorts according to unicode code points, in other words `10` comes before `1`, what you have is a custom sort function that subtracts the two arguments, the current and the next, meaning it sorts numerically instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered perfectly in readily available documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the comparison-function

```
function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
}
```

is used by the sort function.

It's quite simple. The result of each subtraction tells the sort function which argument is greater/smaller, or if they're equal.

```
12 - 3 = 9 // positive result ---> first arg greater than second
10 - 20 = -10 // negative result ---> first arg lesser than second
10 -10 = 0 // equal
```

According to these results, sort-function rearranges the array.

If you'd change it to `return a - b;` sort order would be flipped.

Comment: Hey I have anothr question

Answer (score 1):

That's not the sorting function, it's a call to the *internal* sort function passing a user-given comparison function. That comparison function is simply *used* by `array.sort` (which is deep within Javascript where you can't readily see it) to intelligently swap elements if they're out of order.

The reason it allows user-given comparison function is because you may want revers order, or alpha sorting rather than numeric, or any number of other different ways to sort data.

Comment: only one thing missing, the "how" (comparison result greater/less than zero causes swap, and so on)